# VSCode DevContainers: How do you mount a home file on both MAC and Windows

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am using VSCode devcontainers, how do you have a mount section in the devcontainers.json with that is compatible for both windows and MAC? I have a problem accessing the `source=...` section under the `"mounts"` section.

```json
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/devcontainer.json or this file's README at:
// https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/v0.106.0/containers/python-3
{
    "name": "Python 3",
    "context": "..",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",

    // Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash",
        "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python",
        "python.linting.enabled": true,
        "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
        "python.linting.pylintPath": "venv/bin/pylint",
    },

    // Change <username> to user path (Ex. /Users/vfrank/ on a MAC)
    "mounts": [
        "source=<full home path>/.aws/credentials,target=/home/vscode/.aws/credentials,type=bind,consistency=cached"
    ],
    
    // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
    "extensions": [
        "ms-python.python"
    ],

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    // "forwardPorts": [],

    // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
    "postCreateCommand": "echo 'done'",

    // Uncomment to connect as a non-root user. See https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root.
    "remoteUser": "vscode"
}
```

Works on MAC but not on Windows

```json
    "mounts": [
        "source=${localEnv:HOME}${localEnv:USERPROFILE}/.aws/credentials,target=/home/vscode/.aws/credentials,type=bind,consistency=cached"
    ]
```

Works on windows but not on MAC

```json
    "mounts": [
        "source=~/.aws/credentials,target=/home/vscode/.aws/credentials,type=bind,consistency=cached"
    ]
```

I have docker file sharing setup for C drive on Windows and /Users on MAC, but the error I am getting when using devcontainers is that the folder or file does not exist. I can make it work on both computers so it is not related to file permissions or access from docker.

I am looking for a single `source=...` command that works on both Windows (10+) and MAC.

Comment: your example for Win doesn't work for me. But I make it work like this "source=${localEnv:USERPROFILE}\\.aws\\credentials,target=/root/.aws/credentials,type=bind,consistency=cached"

Answer (score 2):

If you do this:

```
"source=${localEnv:HOME}${localEnv:USERPROFILE}\\.aws\\credentials,target=/root/.aws/credentials,type=bind,consistency=cached"
```

Then only one expansion will be non-empty on each platform and you will get the result you want.

Comment: On a mac this works but windows is resolving both HOME and USERPROFILE and failing

Comment: On windows HOME is not an environmental variable by default, have you set it somewhere?

Comment: Same issue and I couldn't track mine down, something like posh-git probably does it... i added `$env:HOME=''` to the end of my Powershell profile